# [qpid]qpid-python client doesn't work for qpid-0.22

Tags: python, client

I have installed qpid-0.22 on sles11 sp2 X86_64, the broker works fine. 
Then I installed qpid-python client and set the env variable. 
PYTHONPATH=/home/zdx/qpid/qpid-0.22/python/:/usr/local/lib/python2.7:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/home/zdx/qpid/qpid-0.22/python

But the python client doesn't work, including qpid-config tool and qpid-python client test examples. 
When I ran this kind of script, it showed following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/qpid-config", line 31, in

```
from qpid.messaging import Connection
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qpid/**init**.py", line 20, in

```
import connection
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qpid/connection.py", line 20, in

```
import datatypes, session
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qpid/session.py", line 26, in

```
from ops import Command, MessageTransfer
```

ImportError: cannot import name MessageTransfer

It indicate that class or module MessageTransfer does not exist in ops module,
and I look into the python module ops.py, there is none class MessageTransfer.

what is the problem with it?  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you installed the command line tools properly, sometimes you will get this error.
This means that you need to install the `python-qpid` bindings and their libraries.
If you have `epel` repository in your `/etc/yum.repos.d/` , You can directly install the package by using `yum` like this.

```
 #  yum search python-qpid
```

In search results, select package according to your Operating system (32-bit/64-bit).
And then install the package.

```
        # yum install python-qpid..... (python-qpid-proton.x86_64, etc..)
```

If you don't have `epel`, first get `epel` into your `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and then install the package